# Username and Password not accepted nodejs with gmail

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send emails from my gmail account. And i am using my gmail id and password

but it is showing

```
Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z124-20020a633382000000b005c66b54476bsm6420941pgz.63 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (E:\PROJECTS\Neha\orange_rentals\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:790:19)        
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (E:\PROJECTS\Neha\orange_rentals\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1564:34)    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (E:\PROJECTS\Neha\orange_rentals\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:546:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (E:\PROJECTS\Neha\orange_rentals\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:969:20)    
    at SMTPConnection._onData (E:\PROJECTS\Neha\orange_rentals\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:755:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (E:\PROJECTS\Neha\orange_rentals\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:193:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
```

i have not enabled the 2 way auth for the gmail account.

I tried getting app password from this link but security tab there is no such thing app passwords as mentioned on google documentation pages.

https://myaccount.google.com/u/7/?hl=en&utm_source=OGB&utm_medium=act

Here is the code i am using

```
constructor(private logger: AppLogger) {
    const mailConfig = {
      host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
      port: 465,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.MAIL_FROM,
        pass: process.env.MAIL_FROM_PASSWORD
      }
    };
    console.log("file: mail.service.ts:27 ~ MailService ~ constructor ~ mailConfig:", mailConfig);

    try {
      this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailConfig);
    } catch (err) {
      this.logger.error("Unable to connect mail account");
    }
  }

 sendMail(mail: MailOptionsDto) {
    const mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.MAIL_FROM,
      to: mail.toList,
      subject: mail.subject,
      html: mail.body
    };

    if (mail.attachments && mail.attachments.length) {
      mailOptions["attachments"] = mail.attachments;
    }

    return this.transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  }
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into the existing answers? Here is a very similar error that might help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188483/error-invalid-login-535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-accepted